# Batch install Office 2007 KB Updates?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, windows-update

I have over two dozen separate KB updates for Office 2007 with no internet access for Windows Update.

Is there some way I can script or batch install the updates one right after another with no user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these are the best options so far:

http://www.wsusoffline.net/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178995(office.12).aspx

```
@echo off
del %temp%\oupdates.txt /q
for /f "delims=-; tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%i in ('dir /b *kb*.exe') do echo %%j-%%i-%%k-%%l-%%m >> %temp%\oupdates.txt
for /f "delims=-; tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%i in ('type %temp%\oupdates.txt') do %%j-%%i-%%k-%%l-%%m /log:%temp%\officeupdates.log /passive /norestart
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a batch file, some info here, its called chaining hotfixes. It should work for Office updates also

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296861